# Combine tkinter gui and command line args

Tags: python, tkinter, args

I'm trying to both have a gui and a command line option. I have the gui set up and done. But using the following code for the argparsing:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fix a XSL file.')
parser.add_argument('strings', metavar='file', type=str, nargs='+',help='A file for the fixing program.')
args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.strings)
```

When run, returns that there is no module named tkinter. This I believe was because it was set to open with python.exe from python 2. I changed it to open with python 3 but now it is no longer droppable, even if I create a shortcut to it. If I double click it, I get an error that I need to specify a file, that's because its expecting a file drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy. First create a shortcut (this will be the drop point).

For the target do something like: "PATH TO PYTHON EXE" "PATH TO SCRIPT"